# How do I switch Eclipse from Java to C/C++?

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse

I used Eclipse Java last year for a class, and this year I have another class that's requiring us to use Eclipse C. I tried installing the Eclipse C/C++ packages, but when I write in Eclipse it stays in Java. Please help!!!

Also, I don't really want to uninstall Eclipse if I don't have to, because I'm still actively working on projects.

Comment: What do you have in _Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other..._?

Comment: Why is my IDE misbehaving?" questions are frustrating from both sides. To diagnose we often need to see the IDE's configuration, and it's pretty rare that the config can be formatted to fit in a Stack Overflow question. Worse, figuring out which portion of the configuration to show typically requires looking at other pieces of the configuration. In other words, hard to do without sitting at the asker's computer and fishing.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically downloaded 2 "modes" in Eclipse: Java mode, and C/C++ mode. If you type and it assumes it's Java, that's because the project you created is in "Java mode".

First, just quit out of the app and open it again. Maybe the update only enacts when the app is refreshed.
Now go File > New. If it's installed correctly, when you hover over "New", there should be the option "C/C++ Project". If there isn't, double check that you downloaded the correct extension. (Note that I'm on a Mac so the layout might be slightly different for you, but it's the same idea).